# What is another way to construct a quadrilateral with the measure of its four angles?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tkz-euclide

I tried to create a quadrilateral with the measure of its four angles, as shown in the picture:

[image]

My code

```
\documentclass[border=1.5mm,12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\a}{3} 
\tkzDefPoints{0/0/A,\a/0/B}
\tkzDefPointBy[rotation= center A angle 60](B)  
\tkzGetPoint{X}
\tkzDefPointBy[rotation= center B angle -80](A)     
\tkzGetPoint{Y}
\tkzInterLL(A,X)(B,Y)
\tkzGetPoint{Z}
\tkzDefMidPoint(Z,B)
 \tkzGetPoint{C}
\tkzDefPointBy[rotation= center C angle 60](Z)  
\tkzGetPoint{T}
\tkzInterLL(C,T)(A,Z)
\tkzGetPoint{D}
\tkzLabelAngle[pos=.5](Z,B,A){$80^{\circ}$} 
\tkzLabelAngle[pos=.6](B,A,Z){$60^{\circ}$} 
%\tkzLabelAngle[pos=.6](Z,C,D){$30^{\circ}$}    
\tkzLabelAngle[pos=.5](D,C,B){$120^{\circ}$}
\tkzLabelAngle[pos=.5](A,D,C){$100^{\circ}$}
\tkzLabelPoints[](A,B)
%\tkzLabelPoints[above](Z)
\tkzLabelPoints[right](C)
\tkzLabelPoints[left](D)
\tkzDrawPolygon(A,B,C,D)
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Is there another way to construct such a quadrilateral?

Comment: There are many ways to do that but you'll need at least two lengths to start with. You can use `intersections` and/or `calc` libraries to achieve something like that.

Comment: Is there something in particular that you are not happy with? Or do you just want to see other ways?

Comment: @mickep Yes. I want to see other ways.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a much simpler solution with :

```
\tkzDefTriangle[two angles ...

\documentclass[border=1.5mm,12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\a}{6} 
\tkzDefPoints{0/0/A,\a/0/B}
\tkzDefTriangle[two angles = 60 and 80](A,B)
 \tkzGetPoint{Z}
\tkzDefMidPoint(Z,B)
 \tkzGetPoint{C}
\tkzDefTriangle[two angles = 60 and 40](C,Z)
\tkzGetPoint{D}
\tkzLabelAngle[pos=.5](Z,B,A){$80^{\circ}$} 
\tkzLabelAngle[pos=.6](B,A,Z){$60^{\circ}$} 
\tkzLabelAngle[pos=.5](D,C,B){$120^{\circ}$}
\tkzLabelAngle[pos=.5](A,D,C){$100^{\circ}$}
\tkzLabelPoints[](A,B)
\tkzLabelPoints[right](C)
\tkzLabelPoints[left](D)
\tkzDrawPolygon(A,B,C,D)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Update** with the new constraints

```
\documentclass[border=1.5mm,12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\a}{6} 
\pgfmathsetmacro\angleA{60} 
\pgfmathsetmacro\angleB{80}
\pgfmathsetmacro\angleC{120}    
\tkzDefPoints{0/0/A,\a/0/B}
\tkzDefTriangle[two angles = {\angleA} and {\angleB}](A,B)
 \tkzGetPoint{Z}
\tkzDefMidPoint(Z,B)
 \tkzGetPoint{C}
\tkzDefTriangle[two angles = {180-\angleC} and {(180-(\angleA+\angleB))}](C,Z)
\tkzGetPoint{D}
\tkzLabelAngle[pos=.5](Z,B,A){$80^{\circ}$}
\tkzLabelAngle[pos=.6](B,A,Z){$60^{\circ}$}
\tkzLabelAngle[pos=.5](D,C,B){$120^{\circ}$}
\tkzLabelAngle[pos=.5](A,D,C){$100^{\circ}$}
\tkzLabelPoints[](A,B)
\tkzLabelPoints[right](C)
\tkzLabelPoints[left](D)
\tkzDrawPolygon(A,B,C,D)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: If A = 100 degrees, and B = 80 deg. How can I use your code?

Comment: @JohnPaulPeter What is the exact data in this case? Do we know AD? BC? and the others angles ?

Comment: `AD = 5' and `BC= 4`.

Comment: Please make a code automaticaly. 
1) `\tkzDefTriangle[two angles = 60 and 80](A,B)` replace 60 by angleA and 80 by angleB, e.g;
2) \tkzDefTriangle[two angles = 60 and 40](C,Z) replace 60 by 180 - angle C and 40 by 180 - angleA - angleB, e.g.

Comment: @JohnPaulPeter Yes it's possible. There's not enough time, but tomorrow I can do it.

Comment: Doing all this automatically will be easier with the new version of tkz-euclide (tkz-elements) and only lua

Answer (score 6):

If I'm seeing this right, the point *C* is half way between *B* and *Z* where *Z* is just the intersection of *AD* of *BC*.

The intersection of two straight liens can be easily foudn with the [`intersection of` syntax](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/659568).
The halfway point is found via `calc`'s syntax `($(B)!.5!(Z)$)`. (You could also do `\path[overlay] (B) -- coordinate (C) (Z);`.)

Rotating one coordinate around another can be done via `rotate around`:

```
([rotate around=<angle>:(A)]B)
```

or again with the help of `calc`

```
($(A)!1!wa:(B)$)
```

Here we can even change the distance between *A* and the new point. But for the `intersection of` syntax the distance is irrelevant (shouldn't be zero, of course).

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{angles, calc, quotes}
\tikzset{math nodes/.style={execute at begin node=$, execute at end node=$}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  declare function={a=3; wa=60; wb=80; wc=120; wd=100;},
  every label/.append style=math nodes,
  angle eccentricity=1, angle radius=4.5mm,
  pics/angle/.append style={/tikz/nodes={font=\footnotesize}},
]
\coordinate["A" below] (A) at (0,0)
 coordinate["B" below] (B) at (right:a)
 coordinate[overlay]  (B') at ([rotate around=wa:(A)]B)
%coordinate[overlay]  (B') at ($(A)!1!wa:(B)$)
 coordinate[overlay]   (Z) at (intersection of A--B' and B--{[rotate around=-wb:(B)]A})
%coordinate[overlay]   (Z) at (intersection of A--B' and B--{$(B)!1!-wb:(A)$})
 coordinate["C" right] (C) at ($(B)!.5!(Z)$)
 coordinate["D" left ] (D) at (intersection of A--B' and C--{[rotate around=-wc:(C)]B})
%coordinate["D" left ] (D) at (intersection of A--B' and C--{$(C)!1!-wc:(B)$})
;

%\draw[help lines] (D) -- (Z) node[above]{$Z$} -- (C)
%  pic["$\pgfmathprint{int(180-wa-wb)}^\circ$" gray, angle radius=7mm]
%    {angle = D--Z--C};
\draw (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- (D) -- cycle
  foreach \v/\a in {wa/B--A--D, wb/C--B--A,
                   wc/D--C--B, wd/A--D--C}{
    pic["$\pgfmathprint{\v}^\circ$"] {angle/.expand once = \a}
  };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]
[image]

Comment: The placement of the [angle nodes isn't very nice](https://topanswers.xyz/tex?q=4890) when the angles aren't drawn. These can of course be placed differently or with an adjustment to the `angle` pic or …

Comment: 1) Can you create like this `declare function={a=3; wa=60; wb=70; wc=90; wd=360 - wa - wb - wc;}` Then the code automatic to draw.

Comment: @JohnPaulPeter Yes, that is indeed possible. Let me note that instead of PGFMath function you can also simply use macros, as you did in your Q with `\pgfmathsetmacro`.

Comment: There is a bug with`declare function={a=3; wa=90; wb=90; wc=90; wd=90;}`

Comment: @JohnPaulPeter Not really a bug. *Z* doesn't exist then (or only in infinity). Where should *C* lie then?

Comment: Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another way with Asymptote implementation (no worry of redundancy of boundingbox). Also see [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/597948/140722) for calculating and labelling an angle.

Its translation to TikZ is straightforward.

[image]

```
size(6cm);
// change t to control the length AT = t; 
// change s to move C and D
real t=1.2,s=2.5;
pair A=(0,0), T=A+t*dir(60);
pair Bt=rotate(100,T)*A;
pair B=extension(T,Bt,A,A+dir(0));
pair D=A+s*(T-A),Bs=B+dir(100);
pair Ds=rotate(100,D)*A;
pair C=extension(D,Ds,B,Bs);

draw(B--T,red); label("$T$",T,W,red);

draw(A--B--C--D--cycle);
label("$A$",A,SW);
label("$B$",B,SE);
label("$C$",C,NE);
label("$D$",D,NW);


real angleA=degrees(D);
real angleB=180-degrees(C-B);
real angleD=-angleA+degrees(T-B);
real angleC=360-angleA-angleB-angleD;
write("The angle A is: ",angleA);
write("The angle B is: ",angleB);
write("The angle C is: ",angleC);
write("The angle D is: ",angleD);

shipout(bbox(5mm,invisible));
```

Answer (score 2):

For fun, here is a MetaPost/MetaFun suggestion. Compile with `context`.

```
\startMPpage[offset=1DK]
u = 2cm ;

z0 = origin ;
z1 = (5u,0) ;
z2 = z1 + 3u*dir(100) ;
z3 = z2 + whatever*dir(160) = whatever*dir(60) ;

draw z0 -- z1 -- z2 -- z3 -- cycle ;

label.llft( "$A$", z0 ) ;
label.lrt ( "$B$", z1 ) ;
label.urt ( "$C$", z2 ) ;
label.top ( "$D$", z3 ) ;

draw anglebetween( z0--z3, z0--z1, "$\unit{60  degree}$" ) ;
draw anglebetween( z1--z0, z1--z2, "$\unit{80  degree}$" ) ;
draw anglebetween( z2--z1, z2--z3, "$\unit{120 degree}$" ) ;
draw anglebetween( z3--z2, z3--z0, "$\unit{100 degree}$" ) ;
\stopMPpage
```

[image: quadrilateral with angles]

Answer (score 1):

You can use external software capable of exporting "LaTeX" code.
For example `geogebra` and export `tikz`. It's a very simple way.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\pagestyle{empty}
\newcommand{\degre}{\ensuremath{^\circ}}
\begin{document}
\definecolor{uququq}{rgb}{0.25,0.25,0.25}
\definecolor{xdxdff}{rgb}{0.49,0.49,1}
\definecolor{qqwuqq}{rgb}{0,0.39,0}
\definecolor{qqqqff}{rgb}{0,0,1}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,>=triangle 45,x=1.0cm,y=1.0cm]
\clip(-3.3,-2) rectangle (24.02,9.6);
\draw [shift={(1.18,1.92)},color=qqwuqq,fill=qqwuqq,fill opacity=0.1] (0,0) -- (0.64:0.6) arc (0.64:60.64:0.6) -- cycle;
\draw [shift={(3.98,6.9)},color=qqwuqq,fill=qqwuqq,fill opacity=0.1] (0,0) -- (-119.36:0.6) arc (-119.36:-19.36:0.6) -- cycle;
\draw [shift={(8.38,2)},color=qqwuqq,fill=qqwuqq,fill opacity=0.1] (0,0) -- (100.64:0.6) arc (100.64:180.64:0.6) -- cycle;
\draw [shift={(7.71,5.59)},color=qqwuqq,fill=qqwuqq,fill opacity=0.1] (0,0) -- (160.64:0.6) arc (160.64:280.64:0.6) -- cycle;
\draw (1.18,1.92)-- (8.38,2);
\draw (1.18,1.92)-- (3.98,6.9);
\draw (3.98,6.9)-- (7.71,5.59);
\draw (8.38,2)-- (7.71,5.59);
\begin{scriptsize}
\fill [color=qqqqff] (1.18,1.92) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[color=qqqqff] (0.9,2.02) node {$A$};
\fill [color=qqqqff] (8.38,2) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[color=qqqqff] (8.66,2.1) node {$B$};
\draw[color=qqwuqq] (1.62,2.14) node {$60\textrm{\degre}$};
\fill [color=xdxdff] (3.98,6.9) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[color=xdxdff] (3.82,7.12) node {$C$};
\draw[color=qqwuqq] (4.12,6.62) node {$100\textrm{\degre}$};
\fill [color=uququq] (7.71,5.59) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[color=uququq] (7.86,5.86) node {$D$};
\draw[color=qqwuqq] (8.08,2.28) node {$80\textrm{\degre}$};
\draw[color=qqwuqq] (7.44,5.44) node {$120\textrm{\degre}$};
\end{scriptsize}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: quadrangle]